# Does jBASE support Realtime Interactions?

Tags: websocket, real-time-updates, jbase

Does jBASE support web sockets or any other similar technology to offer real-time interaction capabilities? For example, if I am creating a web based dashboard, can I show real time updates on the charts with a jBASE backend?

Answer (score 1):

> Please note, this answer applies to the [Zumasys](https://www.zumasys.com) iteration of jBASE not the Temenos T24 flavor.

As of jBASE 5.7.10, jBASE supports building web based dashboards like this by utilizing the jAgent module to create RESTful APIs that you can use to serve traffic from your jBASE system. You can read more about jAgent at our [Introduction to jAgent](https://docs.zumasys.com/jbase/connectivity/jagent/introduction-to-jagent) guide and you can see more about the the PICK libraries we provide for REST API development at our [APIs](https://docs.zumasys.com/mv-connect/api/) page.

You may also be interested in our [full-stack-with-pick](https://github.com/pickmultivalue/full-stack-with-pick-tutorial) tutorial on GitHub, which includes lessons on:

1. How to set up demo data in jBASE
2. How to set up REST API get endpoints
3. How to set up a simple Vue.js environment
4. How to display a database record with Vue.js

This would give you a recipe on building APIs to access the information you're looking to convey in a dashboard, as well as an idea of how to begin working on the dashboard (as it so happens there are many great, free Vue.js based dashboards available on the internet).

For what it is worth we are evaluating expanding the protocols and technology available within the next iteration of jAgent, including but not limited to a look at implementing web sockets.

Comment: Thanks Mike. We are already using jAgent and have successfully built APIs to get data to our Angular front-end. However, as of now, everything is triggered from the front-end. I was wondering if we can push data from back-end to front-end whenever updates are available. (Kind of what SignalR does in .Net)

Comment: That makes sense. Unfortunately no, nothing built into the framework yet but as I mentioned we are considering that expansion in the next iteration of jAgent. Sounds like you'd be quite interested.

Comment: Yes, Mike. I am interested in a built-in feature like that. Looking forward for it! Thanks!